Manga in which an altar is formed in a classroom and only those who kill can leave the room, after which a battle of teams take place
Manga in which an altar is formed in a classroom and only those who kill can leave the room, after which a battle of teams take place.
Another thing I just remembered was that, in this manga, the main character was good at fighting but he ended up killing one college student and blinding another when he was in sixth grade, after which he promised to never fight against innocent people again. When the altar comes, he only kills those who have killed others.

Another thing I just remembered was that in this manga the MC was good at fighting but he ended up killing one college student and blinding another when he was in sixth grade, after which he promised to never fight against innocent people again, when the altar comes he only kills those who have killed others

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

No need, I got it, it's sovereign of judgement

If you'd like to earn some upvotes and increase your reputation score, you should post a proper answer using the 'Your Answer' field below. Someone else will likely post the answer if you don't, but it might as well be you, since you found it.

Glad you found it. Never know one of my most loved novel had a manga
